# R Programming Random Stock Pick

Tags: r, random, stock

I stuck in a problem with R Programming.
My aim is to randomly select 2 stocks out of the Swiss Market Index, which contains of 30 stocks.

Until now I solved the random pick of the 2 stocks with the following code:

```
SMI_components <- cbind("ABB (ABBN.VX)", "ADECCO (ADEN.VX)", "ACTELION (ATLN.VX)", "JULIUS BAER GRP (BAER.VX)", "RICHEMONT (CFR.VX)", "CREDIT SUISSE (CSGN.VX)", "GEBERIT (GEBN.VX)", "GIVAUDAN (GIVN.VX)", "HOLCIM (HOLN.VX)", "NESTLE (NESN.VX)", "NOVARTIS (NOVN.VX)", "TRANSOCEAN (RIGN.VX)", "ROCHE HOLDING (ROG.VX)", "SWISSCOM (SCMN.VX)", "SGS (SGSN.VX)", "SWISS RE (SREN.VX)", "SYNGENTA (SYNN.VX)", "UBS (UBSG.VX)", "SWATCH GROUP (UHR.VX)", "ZURICH INSURANCE GROUP (ZURN.VX)")

 for(i in 1:1){
 print(sample(SMI_components, 2))
}
```

How do I continue my code, if I want to download the historical data from these two random picked stocks? 
For example, the random selection is:

"NOVARTIS (NOVN.VX)" and "ZURICH INSURANCE GROUP (ZURN.VX)"

how to continue that ...

```
SMI_NOVARTIS <- yahooSeries ("NOVN.VX", from = "2005-01-01", to = "2015-07-30", frequency = "daily")

SMI_ZURICH <- yahooSeries ("ZURN.VX", from = "2005-01-01", to = "2015-07-30", frequency = "daily")
```

I would really appreciate your help
Regards

Comment: `for(i in 1:1)` doesn’t do anything …

Answer (score 1):

`print` outputs to the console but doesn't store anything. So the first thing to do is assign the output of `sample` into a variable.

```
my_picks <- sample(SMI_components, 2)
```

Extract ticker symbol between parens (courtesy the comment below):

```
my_picks <- sub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", my_picks)
```

Then you can use lapply, to call a function (yahooSeries) for each value in `my_picks`.

```
series_list <- lapply(my_picks, yahooSeries, from = "2005-01-01", to = "2015-07-30", frequency = "daily")
```

Then you'll get the output in a list. `series_list[[1]]` will have the output of yahooSeries for the first value of `my_picks`, and `series_list[[2]]` for the second

Lastly, not sure why you bothered with the single-iteration for loop, but you don't need that

Comment: I doubt this will work given the example. `my_picks` has the full name and stock symbol. The function takes the symbol only. You should extract the symbol from each pick.

Comment: Try: `sub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", my_picks)`